# Contar una String

Tags: javascript

Tengo una funcion que recibe dos argumento, primero un array de string llamada "array", segundo un numero entero llamada "numero":
EJ: Funtion contar(array, numero)
Lo que necesito es crear una nueva array que contenga los string que tengan la misma cantidad de caracteres que "numero".
EJ: array(['javascript', 'pedro', 'amigo', 'parque'], 5) debe retornar ['pedro', 'amigo'] ya que pedro y amigo tienen 5 caracteres como pide.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para realizar esa funcionalidad, debes recorrer los elementos del arreglo e ir verificando si el length es igual al número, en caso positivo, lo vas agregando a un arreglo que creaste antes de comenzar el forEach.

```
<script>
    function contar(array,numero){
        respuesta=[];
        array.forEach(element => {
            if(element.length==numero){
                respuesta.push(element);
            }
        });
        return respuesta;
    }
    console.log(contar(['javascript', 'pedro', 'amigo', 'parque'], 5));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar *[str.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/length)* para saber el numero de caracteres que tiene un String, en teoría la función que pides sería así:

```
const largoDeLaPalabra = (palabras, numDeLetras) => {
 const newArray = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < palabras.length; x++) {
      palabras[x].length === numDeLetras ? newArray.push(palabras[x]) : false;
    }
    return(newArray);
}
```